# Using async/await with callback functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I'm trying to build a service layer on top of mongo. I have a `User` object which has an array of referenced `Achievements`.

After I've authenticated the user by JWT or some other means, I enter the service layer and query the relationship as follows.

```
findForUser(userId: string | Types.ObjectId): Promise<Achievement[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    UserSchema.findOne({ _id: userId },
      async (err: any, user: User) => {
        const AchievementMap: Achievement[] = [];

        if (err) throw new Error(err);
        user.achievements?.forEach((a) => {
          // @ts-ignore
          AchievementMap.push(a);
        });
        resolve(AchievementMap);
      });
  });
}
```

What is the async/await approach to returning the result of the callback method passed into `UserSchema.findOne`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findOne` returns an awaitable object - so you don't need to pass a callback to it. Don't try mixing callbacks with `async/await`. The only way to return the value from the callback, as a result of the constructed promise is by using `resolve` (only available in the promise executor).

Instead, make it all `async` - functionally similar but far cleaner.

```
async findForUser(userId: string | Types.ObjectId): Promise<Achievement[]> {
    const user = await UserSchema.findOne({ _id: userId });

    const AchievementMap: Achievement[] = [];
    user.achievements?.forEach(a => {
        AchievementMap.push(a);
    });
    return AchievementMap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is the async/await approach to returning the result of the callback

The `async` and `await` keywords are tools to manage *promises*. They aren't tools to manage callbacks.

The entire point of the code you have in the question is to wrap a promise based API around a function that deals in callbacks.

Now you have a promise you can `await` the return value of `findForUser`.

You can't use `async` and `await` **instead** of creating a promise.